# How do I print a square root to the console in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, console, square-root

I am trying to write code that can print a square root to the console. Here is an example of some code

```py
from math import sqrt

print("ax\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO} + bx + c")

a = int(input("Enter a: "))
b = int(input("Enter b: "))
c = int(input("Enter c: "))

x1 = (-b - sqrt(b ** 2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
x2 = (-b + sqrt(b ** 2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a)

x3 = f"{-b} \N{PLUS-MINUS SIGN} \N{SQUARE ROOT}{b ** 2 - 4*a*c}/{2*a}"

print(f"{a if a != 1 else ''}x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO} {'+' if b > 0 else '-'} {b*-1 if b < 0 else b}x {'+' if c > 0 else '-'} {c*-1 if c < 0 else c}")
print()
print(f"x = {x1}, x = {x2}")
print()
print(f"x = {x3}")
```

The above code just calculates the quadratic formula on given input. I'm not satisfied with the console output styling.

Right now the output look like this `x = 9 ± √101/2`

I was wondering if there was a way (maybe with some extra module like rich?) for me to make an overline for the number

Answer (score 0):

You can use sympy module for display and calculation.

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html

For display purpose:

```
from sympy import *

a,b,c = symbols('a b c', Positive = True, Real = True)
x1 = symbols('\Delta_t', Real = True)

x1 = (-b + sqrt(b ** 2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
x1
```

[image]